# jQuery-validate doesn't not validate the other validation of the field if the first one fails

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two custom validators attached to one field. Unfortunately, when the both conditions fail only the first validation error will be shown. Is it possible to configure the jQuery validator so that it will validate the both validations regardless the result of the first one?

The first validator for the field:

> $.validator.addMethod("datemin", function (value, element, param) {
>
> ```
>     var minimum = Date.parse(param['minimum']),
>         dateValue;
>
>     if (value) {
>         dateValue = Date.parse(value);
>         if (dateValue && (dateValue < minimum)) {
>             return false;
>         } else {
>             return true;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return true;
> });
> ```

The second validator for the field:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("bankday", function (value, element, params) {
            if (value != "") {
                var bankholidays = params['bankholidays'].split(",");

                // If the given date is not among the bank holidays return true otherwise, false
                if ($.inArray(value, bankholidays) == -1) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        });
```

Now when the datemin validator fails it won't validate the second bankday validation at all.

Comment: the shortest answer is no.  jquery validate displays one error message for each field - the error message for the first rule that fails.  There is surely a way to achieve this though.

Comment: If you want a single message when both conditions fail, then you'll need to create a third custom method that checks both things.  It wouldn't hurt for you to have added the rest of the code for this form along with a jsFiddle demo.  A concise example with one or two fields would have been adequate.